# Call rails' assert_equal from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use methods like assert_equal from the console?

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.2.2)
[1] pry(main)> assert_equal(1, 1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_equal' for main:Object
```

Comment: what you using for your tests?

Comment: You presumably need to require whatever library that the test suite is using to define that method. Maybe `require Test::Unit::Assertions`? But anyway, this seems a bit pointless; you could run `1 == 1` to check equality in the console, instead of `assert_equal`.

Comment: Also, if you put a `binding.pry`, or `binding.irb`, or `byebug`, or whatever, in the code **when running the test** (instead of manually running the rails console), then this library would already be loaded, and you'd automatically have access to al of the helper methods like `assert_equal`.